# "For an upload InputStream with no MD5 digest metadata, the markSupported() method must evaluate to true." in Spring Integration AWS

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

**UPDATE**: There is bug in spring-integration-aws-2.3.4

I am integrating SFTP (SftpStreamingMessageSource) as source with S3 as destination.
I have similar Spring Integration configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public S3MessageHandler.UploadMetadataProvider uploadMetadataProvider() {
        return (metadata, message) -> {
            if ( message.getPayload() instanceof DigestInputStream) {
                metadata.setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE );
                // can not read stream to manually compute MD5
                // metadata.setContentMD5("BLABLA==");
                // this is wrong approach:  metadata.setContentMD5(BinaryUtils.toBase64((((DigestInputStream) message.getPayload()).getMessageDigest().digest()));
            }
        };
    }
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpStream")
    public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpSource(SftpRemoteFileTemplate template) {
        SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template);
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("foo");
        messageSource.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
        messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        messageSource.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        messageSource.setCountsEnabled(true);
        return messageSource;
    }
...
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpStream")
    public MessageHandler s3MessageHandler(AmazonS3 amazonS3, S3MessageHandler.UploadMetadataProvider uploadMetadataProvider) {
        S3MessageHandler messageHandler = new S3MessageHandler(amazonS3, "bucketName");
        messageHandler.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        messageHandler.setCountsEnabled(true);
        messageHandler.setCommand(S3MessageHandler.Command.UPLOAD);
        messageHandler.setUploadMetadataProvider(uploadMetadataProvider);
        messageHandler.setKeyExpression(new ValueExpression<>("key"));
        return messageHandler;
    }
```

After start, I am getting following error
`"For an upload InputStream with no MD5 digest metadata, the markSupported() method must evaluate to true."`

This is because `ftpSource` is producing `InputStream` payload without mark/reset support. I  even tried to transform InputStream to `BufferedInputStream` using `@Transformer` e.g. following

```
return new BufferedInputStream((InputStream) message.getPayload());
```

and no success, because then I am getting message "java.io.IOException: Stream closed" because `S3MessageHandler:338` is calling `Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(inputStream)` **which closes stream too early**.

How to generate MD5 for all messages in Spring Integration AWS without pain?

I am using spring-integration-aws-2.3.4.RELEASE

Comment: `spring integration aws is closing stream after computing md5` - what do you mean with this? Any stack traces to share? We just do this `inputStream.reset()` why is that wrong after computing MD5? And yes: I think you are right with that transformer.

Comment: thanks @ArtemBilan. Yes i am getting message "Stream is closed"" because in S3MessageHandler:338 there is call to Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(inputStream) which, for some reason, is calling close() method in the end. Then when reading stream later by S3 handler it crash in stream closed message.
I am using spring-integration-aws-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `S3MessageHandler` does this:

```
if (payload instanceof InputStream) {
                InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) payload;
                if (metadata.getContentMD5() == null) {
                    Assert.state(inputStream.markSupported(),
                            "For an upload InputStream with no MD5 digest metadata, "
                                    + "the markSupported() method must evaluate to true.");
                    String contentMd5 = Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(inputStream);
                    metadata.setContentMD5(contentMd5);
                    inputStream.reset();
                }
                putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, inputStream, metadata);
            }
```

Where that `Md5Utils.md5AsBase64()` closes an `InputStream` in the end - bad for us.

This is an omission on our side. Please, raise a GH issue and we will fix it ASAP. Or feel free to provide a contribution.

As a workaround I would suggest to have a transformer upfront of this `S3MessageHandler` with the code like:

```
return org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);
```

This way you will have already a `byte[]` as a payload for the `S3MessageHandler`  which will use a different branch for processing:

```
 else if (payload instanceof byte[]) {
                byte[] payloadBytes = (byte[]) payload;
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(payloadBytes);
                if (metadata.getContentMD5() == null) {
                    String contentMd5 = Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(inputStream);
                    metadata.setContentMD5(contentMd5);
                    inputStream.reset();
                }
                if (metadata.getContentLength() == 0) {
                    metadata.setContentLength(payloadBytes.length);
                }
                putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, inputStream, metadata);
            }
```

Comment: yes I had that feeling. This workaround is working nice, thanks a lot

Comment: The fix is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/commit/9a434b833aa58f4fe99889882a64d8c157c3ad1f